# Can Derived class hide the accessors - Whats wrong with code below

Tags: c#, inheritance, accessor

I am trying to hide the accessors in derived class, is it valid? My system did not respond back on executing.

```
class BaseCS
  {
      private string name;

      public string Name
      {
          get { return name; }
          set { name = "Base " + value; }
      }    
  }

  class DerivedCS : BaseCS
  {
      public new string Name
      {
          set { Name = "Der " + value; }
          get { return Name; }
      }
  }

public static void Main()
        {
            BaseCS one = new DerivedCS();

            one.Name = "One";

            Console.WriteLine("Name of object one is {0} ", one.Name);


            ((BaseCS)one).Name = "On1";
            Console.WriteLine("Name of object one is {0} ", one.Name);
        }
```

Shouldn't I expect output to be,

```
Name of object one is Base Der One
Name of object one is Base On1
```

Comment: Why do you use new for this? You can use virtual if you want to have polymorphic behavior in C#.

Answer (score 2):

1. This code:

   ```
   public new string Name
   {
       set { Name = "Der " + value; }
       get { return Name; }
   }
   ```

   Will lead to stack overflow, because `Name` in getters and setters will refer to `Name` in `DerivedCS`, not in `BaseCS`. `Name` property will call itself forever, until crashing. You need to use `base.Name`.
2. What you probably want is polymorphysm. You should make property `virtual` and `override` setter in the derived class.

   If you do not use virtual properties, the following object will not behave the way you want:

   ```
   BaseCS one = new DerivedCS();
   one.Name = "name"; // base implementation is called
   ```
3. Changing property value in setter is usually a bad idea. Users expect the following contract to be followed:

   ```
   var a = new A();
   a.Foo = "bar";
   Debig.Assert(a.Foo == "bar");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should be doing

```
    class BaseCS
    {
        private string name;

        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = "Base " + value; }
        }

    }

    class DerivedCS : BaseCS
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            set { base.Name = "Der " + value; }
            get { return base.Name; }
        }
    }
```

OR with a new keyword

```
 class BaseCS
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        set { name = "Base " + value; }
    }

}

class DerivedCS : BaseCS
{
    public new  string Name
    {
        set { base.Name = "Der " + value; }
        get { return base.Name; }
    }
}

now you should create the object as the derived type to get your expected result

     DerivedCS one = new DerivedCS();
```